# Paint.net is good, but cannot easily draw Text with a white background?

Tags: paint.net

I have been using Irfan View for a few years but then saw Paint.net today here on Superuser.

It seems quite good except that when you write text, there seems to be no easy way to have a solid background, so the text blur into the photos and is not readable.

Is there any easy way to do that?  (beside drawing a white rectangle first, which is not preferred because the size is unknown at first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of right now would be to create the text in a new layer above, then create a new layer below the text in which you draw a filled white rectangle. Then you can merge both again.

Comment: complicated but can work.  maybe they can make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Try following those steps

1. Create a new layer
2. Fill the new layer with a single color, for example black
3. Write the text in the new layer, for example in white.
4. Effects Style Outline with Thickness of 4 (low res image / small sized font) to 10 high res image / large sized font) and intensity of 50.
5. Magic wand select the background and click Delete (keep repeating this step for "holes" in characters like 'p'
6. Layers, Merge Layer Down

Comment: Welcome Svarvsven. Try to write some comment lines too, just to help the general understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could also format the text appear with an outline color which is different from the text color, then you don't need a white background rectangle to read the text. Most decent graphics tools can do that, surely Paint.net too.

Answer (score -1):

1) Make a white layer
2) type your text on the white layer
3) copy it
4) paste it on the desired layer and move it into position.